# how to ask bazel to give me the path of a built artifact?

Tags: bazel

I have (for example) a `cc_binary` rule that builds an executable.  It builds into the cache, obviously, somewhere like `$HOME/.cache/.bazel/............/k8-fastbuild/bin/...../here-is-my-exe`.

How do I get this path from bazel, from a bash command line?  I was looking at the `query` family of bazel subcommands but didn't spot a likely function.  (Actually, I don't really know what I'm doing when it comes to bazel queries.)

EDIT:

I have found `bazel aquery 'outputs(".*exe-name-here", bazel-target-here)'` which, if I grep for `Output:` gives me a path starting at `bazel-out`.  Which is ok, except that I'd really really like an absolute path or at least one starting from `.cache` so that it has the magic generated directory names.

(E.g., like `/home/david/.cache/bazel/_bazel_david/c40902ece5403d82118f5676fd37fdb6/execroot/tracklet_linker/bazel-out/...`)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the built executable? If you want to run it then you can use bazel run //target -- args

Comment: ah, thank you @JamesSharpe I did not know that!  That solves some use cases but I would like to also have a way to get the path as stated so I can later run scripts, outside of bazel, that actually can directly access the file via its full path.

Comment: The full output structure is documented here: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/output_directories.html
You can run bazel info output_base to find the base directory for the build output then binaries are relative to execroot; exact path depends on build structure and config flags passed

Comment: You also have the convenience symlink bazel-bin which is the base directory for the last complete build. You can then run readlink on this to find the full path.

Comment: `bazel info` is another good tip, thanks @JamesSharpe - the symlinks weren't being created due to dockerfile uid/gid issues ...

Comment: Another nice trick is to `bazel run --run_under="echo" //your/target:binary`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bazel: How do you get the path to a generated file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859615/bazel-how-do-you-get-the-path-to-a-generated-file)

Comment: @GenuinePlaceholder - indeed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76906888/751579) looks like it'll work, given changes to Bazel since this question was asked, but I'm not able to verify this at this time (not working with Bazel now).

Comment: Awesome, hopefully it helps someone else