# Get bazel-bin directory easily in the terminal

Tags: bazel

I have generated some output files using `bazel build`, but its is a bit tedious to specify the path of the bazel-bin directory everytime I need to access the output.

In deeply nested bazel projects, not only do I need to get the specific repository, `/Users/username/repos/organisation/folder/folder/repo`, I also need to add the `bazel-bin/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/binary_i_want`. I would prefer to say `$output/binary_i_want`. Bazel should be able to get the project directory (as it looks up the workspace file), and find the `bazel-bin`, and then look for the equivalent directory I am in. This is because I might not be running it directly, but instead copying this file to an android device, with adb push.

Is this possible? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `$(bazel info bazel-bin)/binary_i_want` for this.

Edit: Getting the complete path to an artifact generate by a rule is a bit more involved. One option using `jq` could be:

`$(bazel info workspace)/$(bazel aquery //:some_path --output jsonproto 2>/dev/null | jq -r ".artifacts[0].execPath")`

(Inspired by this answer: [Bazel: How do you get the path to a generated file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859615/bazel-how-do-you-get-the-path-to-a-generated-file))

Comment: Thanks @SjoerdVisscher, however is there a way to also include the current relative-to-project-root path as well? The tensorflow repo is very nested :D

Comment: @BenButterworth sorry, I missed that part of you question. I updated my answer.

Comment: I have to say, I was looking for a simple answer, but now I have learnt about [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and action queries! And more about bazel in general. Unfortunately the query returns `bazel-out` directories, instead of `bazel-bin`. I'm not clear on the differences, so I'll read more about it. It looks like bazel-bin 2 levels inside bazel-out, inside a architecture directory. `e.g. tensorflow/bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin`.

Comment: @BenButterworth this documentation covers the output directory relations https://bazel.build/remote/output-directories#layout